# Does a 3D engine needs to analyse all the map objects before rendering

Tags: game-engine, 3d-rendering

Does a 3D engine needs to analyse every single object on the map to see if it's gonna be rendered or not. My understanding is that a **line** from the **center of projection** to a **pixel** in the **view plan**, the engine will find the closest plan that intersect with it, but wouldn't that mean that for each pixel the engine needs to analyse **all objects** in the map, is there a way to limits the objects analysed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's the task of acceleration data structures like grids, kd-trees, bounding volume hierarchies etc.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks, why not put this in an answer ! you got me what i wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such procedure are called **[frustum-culling algorithm](http://cgvr.informatik.uni-bremen.de/teaching/cg_literatur/lighthouse3d_view_frustum_culling/index.html)**.

You can also find more information about it here :-

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum (wiki)
- http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/
- http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/vfc.pdf (better but hard to read)
  IMHO, this last link is similar as what *Nico Schertler* mentioned in comment.

Beware, what you seek for is not the same as "[**occlusion culling**](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3394/occlusion_culling_algorithms.php?print=1)" (another related link "[Most efficient algorithm for mesh-level, optimal occlusion culling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317622/most-efficient-algorithm-for-mesh-level-optimal-occlusion-culling) ) ", which is another optimization when an object is totally hidden behind another one.

Note that most game-engine render by object (a pack of many triangles - via [**draw calls**](https://www.pcper.com/reviews/Editorial/What-Exactly-Draw-Call-and-What-Can-It-Do), roughly speaking ), not by tracing each pixel (**[ray-tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics))**) as you might understand.

Ray-tracing is too expensive in most real-time application.

Comment: thank you very much, but i think you missed what i want, before doing the frustum culling, i need something to limit the object for the frustum culling to be more efficient. like when frustum culling limit the objects to analyse to those inside the frustum volume making occlusion culling faster, i can't just analyse all the object of the map each time i do the frustum culling.

Comment: @habibhassani  Do you mean an algorithm/data-structure that can take advantages on the assumption : the result (list of objects inside the view) of previous frame and current frame are not so different?  If so, the pdf link may probably cover what you want.